# Does optimizing for size reduce runtime memory usage as well as binary size?

Tags: compiling, memory, c, gcc

Does optimizing for size with `gcc -Os` *only* reduce the binary size of a program, or does it reduce its runtime memory usage as well? I know what *exactly* the results are depend on the specific code, but in general is the result a lower memory usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, since the program needs to be loaded into memory, `-Os` will result in lower memory usage. But that is the only effect on memory usage it will have.

Comment: If it's smaller wouldn't it mean the internal wiring is also different and potentially faster, potentially using less memory in other ways?

Comment: I don't think so. The size of the code is reduced, not the size of the data structures.

Comment: Its possible to reduce the size of the data structures by packing things closer together.  This may make the code slower, since it has to unpack at runtime.  I'm not sure if -Os actually does this, but it is possible.

Comment: @KeithB: The man page of gcc clearly says `-Os` optimizes for code size. Packing and unpacking data structures would _increase_ code size.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It may just be doing aligned versus unaligned reads at the assembly level. I was thinking of the case where instead of padding an array of structures so that each element is aligned, they are arranged without padding.

Comment: While possible in theory, changing the layout would break compatibility with binaries compiled without `-Os`. There is also the question of what the C standard requires.

Comment: "The size of the code is reduced, not the size of the data structures." Yes, but I was thinking more like it could change when it pulls variables into the stack, or the order of malloc/free in certain circumstances. Like I said though, I have no idea, which is why I asked =]

Answer (score 3):

One aspect is that -Os will try to give you a smaller application, and since it is smaller *sometimes* it will execute faster since there is less code to execute.

Comment: Can you expand this answer and defend it against the conflicting information in [Kim's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13800/gcc-os-optimization/13813#13813)?

Comment: It has a lot to do on what platform, and what kind of code is compiled. Sometimes it is faster to use a bigger binary with a lot of in-lined code, and sometimes that in-line cost time to execute. It depends amongst other things on things like the size of the pipeline in the cpu and the cost of cache misses etc etc. Look at the extremes and compare a Desktop PC with a AVR mcu, the -Os will have quite different behaviour on the system. It is not black and white...

Comment: Here's one reference: http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/category/gcc. But on the contrary: http://transient-inode.blogspot.com/2009/03/gcc-os-vs-o2-linux-kernel.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually, according to some sources like [gentoo-wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/CFLAGS#-Os), the `-Os` flag **can** have more benefits than just reduced binary footprint. **But** extensive usage of it can cause problems. The actual benefits can be seen for large programs, but as the flag can trigger some bugs, one must be careful not to use it with unstable code. So, unfortunately, this means that really large pieces of software are more likely to expose bugs (by pure probability: more code => higher risk of bugs exposure). Many large applications *filter this flag out* at build-time to prevent such bugs from being exposed.

Also keep in mind that `-Os` only *can* make an application faster - this is not a rule. What is certain about it is that the compiler will *try* to make the program smaller.

Answer (score 1):

As Kim says, the resulting binary is smaller, so the stack memory usage will be smaller too.

It might also be faster than some other optimisation flags, because more of the program will fit into the CPU caches.  That's one reason it has become more popular of late.